# Find documents of user with a specific field contents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a few documents that looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : <object id>,
    "user_id" : 1,
    "country" : "NZ",
    "file_name" : "hi.zip",
    "extension" : "zip",
    "mime_type" : "application/zip",
    "size" : 226679,
    "location" : "https://somecontainer.blob.core.windows.net/userdata/m/hh1/hi.zip"
}
```

I have two users with `user_id` as `1` and `2` and different `file_name`, what I want to do is to get `user_1: 1` with `file_name: ['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']` and then delete it.

Currently I am doing this:

```py
for file_name in db.collection.find({'user_id': 3}):
    if file_name['file_name'] in ['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']:
        db.collection.delete_one({'_id': file_name['_id']})
```

Is there a more MongoDB way of doing this?

I tried doing:

```py
for file_name in db.collection.find({'user_id': 3}, {"_id": 1, 'location':1, "file_name": {'$elemMatch':{'$in':['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']}}}):
    print(file_name)
```

This just prints all the documents, I tried `$eq` too.

Comment: have you tried `db.collection.find({user_id: 3, file_name: {$in: ['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']}})` ?

Comment: Ya, that worked. Can you post it as an answer? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter using `$in` operator. Mongodb will match documents whose field contains at least one element in the array you're looking for. [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) . so your query will be like so:

```
db.collection.find({user_id: 3, file_name: {$in: ['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']}})
```

or even better you can delete them all using `deleteMany()` method in mongodb. So you don't have to loop over it again in your code.

```
db.collection.deleteMany({user_id: 3, file_name: {$in: ['hi.zip', 'hello.zip']}})
```